# Trying to get button to stay highlighted after click which triggers a render

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I'm building a survey and right now I have a component that takes an array of questions with conditions and renders a question then following a click from the user renders the next question based on if the condition is met. When one of the answer buttons is clicked (say for Q1) it changes colour using css focus to highlight to the user the answer chosen, the issue is that when the next question appears (say Q2) and the next answer is clicked the highlighting from the first questions answer returns to default and only the second questions answer is highlighted.

Is there a way to keep all answers selected highlighted using css or will I have to make changes to the component itself.

So far the code looks like the following

```
const QuestionBox = ({ question, answer, onSelect }) => {
  const { questions, answers } = question;
  return (
    <div>
      <p>
        {question.question}
        <br/>
        {answers.map((text, index) => (
          <button
            className='questionBtns'
            key={index}
            onClick={() => {
              onSelect(text);
            }}
          >
            {text}
          </button>
        ))}
      </p>
    </div>
  );
};
export default QuestionBox;

class Survey extends Component {
   state = {
      answers: {};
   };

   render() {
     return (
       <div>                 
          {questions.map(question => (
              <QuestionBox
                  question={question}
                  answer={this.state.answers[question.questionId]}
                  key={question.questionId}
                  onSelect={answer => {
                       const answers = {
                            ...this.state.answers,
                            [question.questionId]: answer,
                   };
                  this.setState({ answers });
                 }}
                />
            ))}                       
          </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// Question box should only know these things:
// 1. a single question
// 2. choices for that question
//   - each choice should have an id and text
// 3. function to select one of the choices
// 4. previously selected choice

// I have renamed and restructured stuff which is better suited in this scenario

const QuestionBox = ({ question, choices, selectChoice, previouslySelectedChoiceID }) => {

    // if some choice is already selected, highlight the button
    const buttonStyleClass = previouslySelectedChoiceID !== -1 ?  "some-hightlight-class" : "normal-class";

    return (
    <div>
      <p>
        {question}
        <br/>
        {choices.map(choice => (
          <button
            key={choice.id}
            onClick={() => {
                selectChoice(question.id, choice.id);
            }}
            className={buttonStyleClass}
          >
            {choice.text}
          </button>
        ))}
      </p>
    </div>
  );
};
export default QuestionBox;

//---------------------------------------------------
class Survey extends Component {
   state = {
      selectedChoices: [],
       // structure : 
      // [ { questionID : x, selectedChoiceID : y } ]
      questions: [], // assuming that questions are stored in state
      // structure : 
      // [ { id: x, text: x, choices: [ {id: y, text: z} ]}]
   };

   getSelectedChoiceForQuestionId = (questionID) =>{
        const {selectedChoices} = this.state;
        const index =  selectedChoices.findIndex( ch => ch.questionID === questionID) ;
        return index === -1 ? -1 : selectedChoices[index].selectedChoiceID;
   }

   handleSelectChoice = (questionID, selectedChoiceID) => {
       const {selectedChoices} = this.state;
        const index = selectedChoices.findIndex(x => x.questionID === questionID);
        // if selection is done for the first time,
        if (index === -1){
            selectedChoices.push({questionID, selectedChoiceID}); // shorthand
        }
        // else change the selection to something else
        // if you only want the users to select once only, remove the else part
        else{
            selectedChoices[index].selectedChoiceID = selectedChoiceID;
        }

   }

   render() {
    const {questions} = this.state;
     return (
       <div>                 
          {questions.map(question => (
              <QuestionBox
                  question={question.text}
                  choices={question.choices}
                  previouslySelectedChoiceID={this.getSelectedChoiceForQuestionId(question.id)}
                  selectChoice={this.handleSelectChoice}
                  key={question.id}
                />
            ))}                       
          </div>
     )}

}
```